# How to describe touching integer intervals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have multiple integer intervals represented as

$[0,2], [2,2], [4,7], [2,4]$ etc.

Notice that these intervals are allowed to touch each other at their beginnings and ends. They are not allowed to overlay each other, e.g. $[1,5],[1,2]$ is forbidden.

Given a set of those intervals $[x_1,x_2],...,[x_{2n-1},x_{2n}]$ with $n$ the number of intervals, how can I consicely describe them in mathematical notation under the given constraints?

Comment: Why insist on notation when words are probably easier to understand?

Comment: @lhf Hmm, it will be part of some pseudocode and I didn't want to escape to natural language. But I agree, using words is probably easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

One way to require is that their "interiors" are pairwise disjoint.

If $[a,b]=\{x\mid a\leq x\leq b\}$, then we write $(a,b)=\{x\mid a<x<b\}$. If all the intervals have non-empty interiors, then your requirement is exactly the same requiring that the interiors are pairwise disjoint. But since you allow empty interior then you should also require that $[a,b]\subseteq[c,d]$ if and only if $[a,b]=[c,d]$ as well.

Another method is to say that if $[a,b]\cap[c,d]\neq\varnothing$ then either $b=c$ or $a=d$.

Comment: Hm, regarding the interiors, I thought about that, but what do you do for $[0,1],[0,2]$? This is forbidden, yet their interiors are different with the first having none, and the second just ${1}$. Regarding the intersection method, $[0,1] \cap [0,2]=[0,1] \neq \emptyset$ but neither $b=c$ nor $a=d$, or did I misunderstood what you wrote?

Comment: @neo: Hm. It seems that you are correct. One possibility is to require that there is no inclusions in addition to the interiors being disjoint. I'll update.

Comment: What about your last sentence in the answer? As I wrote, I think this is not correct. Maybe just remove it, then I can accept it as answer.

Comment: But if $[a,b]\subseteq[c,d]$ then their intersection is non-empty.

Comment: Yes, but what does this have to do with "$b=c$ or $a=d$"?

Comment: @neo, the idea is that if they intersect then we require them to be of the form $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$, in which case the intersection is necessarily $\{b\}$.